# pygame group update method not working

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a game similar to Space Invaders but the sprite group update method is not working.

The `pygame.sprite.Group.update` method is not updating the objects in the list one by one but instead it is causing all the objects stored in the list to take the value of the first object.

The class to design the aliens:

```
class Alien(Sprite):
    def __init__(self,screen,ai):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("C:\\Users\\ozzy\\Desktop\\project alien invasion\\alien.bmp")
        self.screen = screen
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.ai = ai
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
```

to move the fleet to the right

```
def update(self):
    self.x += 3
    self.rect.x = self.x
```

to create the fleet

```
def create_fleet(screen,ai,aliens,ship):    

    alien = Alien(screen,ai)
    alien_width = alien.rect.width
    alien_height = alien.rect.height
    number_alien_x = get_number_x(ai,alien_width)
    number_alien_y = get_number_y(ai,alien_height,ship)
    for alien_coloum in range(number_alien_y):
       for alien_row in range(number_alien_x):
          create_aliens(screen,ai,alien_width,aliens,alien_row,alien_coloum)
```

to get the number of rows that can fit on the display

```
def get_number_y(ai,alien_height,ship):

    available_space_y = (ai.height - ship.rect.height -(3 * alien_height))
    number_of_rows = int(available_space_y / (2 * alien_height))
    return number_of_rows
```

to  get the number of columns that can fit on the screen

```
def get_number_x(ai,alien_width):

    available_space_x = ai.width - 2 * alien_width
    number_of_aliens = int(available_space_x /(2 * alien_width))
    return number_of_aliens
```

to store the fleet in group

```
def create_aliens(screen,ai,alien_width,aliens,alien_row,alien_coloum):

    alien = Alien(screen,ai)
    alien_x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_row
    alien.rect.x = alien_x
    alien.rect.y = alien.rect.height + 2 * alien.rect.height * alien_coloum
    aliens.add(alien)
```

to call the update method on the group

```
def update_aliens(aliens):


    for a in aliens.sprites():
       print(a.rect.x)
    aliens.update()
    #the update method cause the x co ordintes to be same first object
    for a in aliens.sprites():
       print(a.rect.x)


#main method
aliens = Group()
create_fleet(screen,ai,aliens,ship)
while True:
   update_aliens(aliens)
```

Before calling the update method the aliens in the group have distinct x coordinates but after the update method they all have the same x coordinate.

Can someone explain what is wrong? Does the function produce some kind of side effect?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of these separate code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Define `self.x` in the `update()` method, not the `__init__()` method